# Reusing EBS snapshots on a different percona xtradb cluster node

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, percona

I'm evaluating a Percona xtradb 5.6 cluster of 3 nodes in AWS environment. I'm using `ec2-consistent-snapshot` with `--mysql` to make an EBS snapshot of the data. However when a snapshot was made on `node 1`, and then `node 2` is relaunched using that snapshot, the cluster would break.

Through trial-and-error I've found that this is caused by reusing `auto.cnf` and `gvwstate.dat` files in mysql datadir, which would contain ids of `node 1`, and the issues were (apparently) caused by another node trying to join with id of another node already in cluster. Removing the said files appears to have fixed the issue and now nodes go up and down as expected.

My question is: did I do the right thing? Do I need to remove auto.cnf and gvwstate.dat before using another server's datadir? Do I need to do anything else? What's the standard practice for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did was correct. However, be sure to check your gcache size to avoid SST. It is quite possible that you could take the ebs-snap now, go to lunch, come back and create node3 using that snap, start mysql up and an SST happens anyway.

I would check your logs on the new node to ensure that an SST did NOT happen.